# AutoScrollLabel - Marquee Label

Tags: uilabel, marquee, autoscroll

I have been trying to implement UILabel with scrolling/moving text. And while exploring various options, I came across AutoScrollLabel (https://github.com/cbess/AutoScrollLabel). But didn't find clear instructions on how to implement it with using swift. Anyone used it?

Anyone implemented UILabel with dynamic moving text, please share.

Answer (score 2):

It is fairly simple with [MarqueeLabel](https://github.com/cbpowell/MarqueeLabel)

Just copy the MarqueeLabel.swift file into your project, make a label then change its class to MarqueeLabel as shown in Image here.. [MarqueeClassImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0aeX.png)

then setup the label like this.....

```
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollingLabel: MarqueeLabel!

    scrollingLabel.text = textOutput
    scrollingLabel.type = .continuous 
    scrollingLabel.speed = .rate(80)
    scrollingLabel.fadeLength = 80.0
    scrollingLabel.labelWillBeginScroll()
```

There are various options on how you setup and control the label, have a ready through the documentation at the link above.

Comment: Yes was able to achieve it using MarqueeLabel. Thanks :)